# JQuery UI Tabs issues creating first tab dynamically

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm stucked with JQueryUI tabs with a silly issue.
Basically I'm adding the first tab and I cannot find a way to select it. The content doesn't get displayed until I click on the tab button.

The issue can be easily reproduce with one of the examples provided on JQueryUI page:
http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation

To reproduce:
1) Delete the tab you see when you load the page
2) Add a new tab
3) New tab content is not displayed until you click over the button.

I've tried several things to overcome this behavior, but none of them worked...

Can someone help me out??

Thanks and best regards.

Sergio

Answer (score 0):

In the `addTab` function you can set the current selected tab as the last inserted by the function.

Code:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs( "select", $( "#tabs" ).tabs("length")-1 );
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/bw9ST/

Comment: Hi, this is the solution that worked for me
'if (tabsIndex == 0 && tabsCounter == 1) {
     //Selecting first tab when it is the only one
     tabsElem.tabs( "option", "active", 0 );
}'

Comment: I wanted to select first tab when it was the only one created, I used active but at first I was mislead by the fact the tabs("option", "active") returns false